# On click function firing more times every time button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, razor

I had an initial issue where I could not get a button within a modal to work. 
I got my solution; however, it ended up breaking the main screen table's button events. I figured separating the scripts into different files and including the file to use specific js files on certain cshmtl pages would solve my problem; however, it's causing me more grief. I had all of these scripts in one file, if there is a solution where all my buttons work inside and outside the modal, I will be happy to take that route.

I think I have it just about figured out -- but now when I click the "add user" button once it's fine. If i click it twice, two modals pop up. If I click it 3 times it freaks out. I am unsure what to do about the problem. I am not the most proficient in js/jQuery, very new and learning.

Main Page:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/Maintenance.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/Index.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/js/Maintenance.js"></script>


<div class="tableContainer">

    <div class="maintHeader">
        <div class="headerText">
            All Users

@*This button is the one causing issues -----------------------------------*@

            <button class="sqButton btnGreen float-right" title="Register" 
                data-toggle="ajax-modal" 
                data-target="#register" 
                data-url="@Url.Action("Register", "Home")">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
            </button>

@*-------------------------------------------------------------------------*@
        </div>
    </div>

    @if (Model.Any())
    {
        //--Table Header Declaration--
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="scrollTable">

                <table class="table table-hover table-md ">

                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th class="text-left tableHead d-none">Id</th>
                            <th class="text-left tableHead">User Name</th>
                            <th class="text-left tableHead">Email</th>
                            <th class="text-left tableHead">Phone Number</th>
                            <th class="text-left tableHead">City</th>
                            <th class="text-left tableHead text-right">Remove</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>

                    @*--Table Body For Each to pull DB records--*@
                    <tbody>
                        @foreach (var user in Model)
                        {
                            @Html.Partial("~/Views/Administration/Users/UserTable.cshtml", user)
                        }
                    </tbody>

                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
    <div id="modal-placeholder"></div>
</div>
```

Modal HTML:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/Modals.css" />
<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/js/MaintModals.js"></script>

<div class="modal fade" id="login" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="loginLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static">
    <div class="modal-dialog modalPosition" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header headerFormat">
                <span class="modal-title TitleFont">Login</span>
                <button type="button" class="close closePadding" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span class="xColor" aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form method="post" class="mt-3" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Login">
                    <div class="form-group row text-center">
                        <label class="col-sm-3 text-right col-form-label labelFont" asp-for="Email"></label>
                        <div class="col-sm-7">
                            <input asp-for="Email" class="formField" />
                            <span asp-validation-for="Email" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row text-center">
                        <label class="col-sm-3 text-right col-form-label labelFont" asp-for="Password"></label>
                        <div class="col-sm-7">
                            <input asp-for="Password" class="formField" />
                            <span asp-validation-for="Password" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row text-center">
                        <label asp-for="RememberMe" class="col-sm-4 text-right col-form-label labelFont" />
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <input asp-for="RememberMe" />
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.RememberMe)
                        </div>
                    </div>


                    <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>

                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary padFloat green">Login</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary padFloat blue" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Maintenance.js:

```js
$(function () {
    var placeholderElement = $('#modal-placeholder');

    $('[data-toggle="ajax-modal"]').click(function (event) {
        var url = $(this).data('url');
        $.get(url).done(function (data) {
            placeholderElement.html(data);
            placeholderElement.find('.modal').modal('show');
        });
    });
});
```

MaintModal.js:

```js
$(function () {
    $(document).on('click', '[data-dismiss="modal"]', function () {
        $(".modal-backdrop").remove();
    });
});

$(function () {
    var placeholderElement = $('#modal-placeholder');

    $(document).on('click', '[data-toggle="ajax-modal"]', function (event) {
        var url = $(this).data('url');
        $.get(url).done(function (data) {
            placeholderElement.html(data);
            placeholderElement.find('.modal').modal('show');
        });
    });
});
```

site.js:

```js
$('.sqButton').click( function (event) {  
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

I just want my parent table's buttons to work and the buttons within the modal to work. I attempted to unbind (`$('[data-toggle="ajax-modal"]').unbind("click");`) the event before each event but that fixed nothing.

I am sure there's a simple way to do it. I have just been dancing around it and making it more complicated than it should be.

Comment: Can you not have an overlay when the modal pops-up ? so that the add user button can not be clicked ?

I faced this issue some years back, and functionality wise it made sense to put an overlay/disable everything else when you are working with the modal.

Comment: @vS12 , i probably did not explain clearly or i am misunderstanding you. 

The overlay i works fine, it's when im in the main page and click the add button once, i'll get one modal (appropriately) but if i click out of the modal, click on add again I'll get 2 modals.  It's like the click event is increasingly firing the more times i click on the add button.

Comment: Are you destroying the previous modal on closing ? I guess the previous modal object stays and once you click on the button again it creates a new one, and then for rendering some class action is triggered which then opens all the modals.

Comment: @vS12 I am going to guess I am not, any recommendations on how?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/P9qjg/ - check this.

It is not too complicated, you can search further if the above link does not work. This is a common issue with the modals because of the rendering being done on the basis of class names

Comment: @vS12 , so would i use that instead of `placeholderElement.find('.modal').modal('show');` line

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200863/discussion-between-vs12-and-s-kellar).